# Authenticating Hybrid Mobile Application with ADFS behind firewall

Tags: authentication, mobile, vpn, saml, adfs

We are planning to develop and enterprise tablet application using Kendo Mobile (Phonegap+Javascript). All the services required for the application would be developed using ASP.NET Web API technology and they need to be secured.

Users tablet application need to be authenticated using ADFS which is behind corporate firewall. We can open site to site VPN tunnel between our Azure network and corporate network to allow access to ADFS from  service layer on  Azure.

Tablets are not going to have VPN connection to corporate neytwork. Now the question is how do we authenticate mobile users with ADFS using SAML? Read quite a bit about Active/Passive authentication schemes, but they need access to ADFS directly from tablet. Since we can not have, can we have an authentication service on Azure which can talk to ADFS over VPN tunnel and provide some token to tablet and tablet use that token to talk to protected services?

I would appreciate from anyone that has experienced the same problem and how you addressed

Answer (score 1):

I assume your API (WebApi based) is hosted on Azure, right?

Obtaining a token from an STS in a mobile client, usually involves delegating the authentication to a web browser (using passive profile) and then extracting the token with then it becomes available. This is often the case with STSs that don't support "Active Profile" (an endpoint where you can send client credentials and receive a security token in exchange). ADFS supports this (through WS-Trust), but you don't want ADFS exposed to the internet (you could though, and ADFS has a specific role for this without the need for a VPN).

This technique is illustrated in [this sample](https://docs.auth0.com/win8-tutorial). PhoneGap will likely have an equivalent.

A (simpler?) way in your case might be to get a Windows Azure AD (WAAD) account, and use DirSync to synch your AD there and then use WAAD as the STS (in-lieu of ADFS). WAAD is by definition exposed to internet, so you don't need to VPN or anything. The latest release of DirSync will synchronize password hashes too. The architecture of this is similar to what is described [in this blog post](http://blog.auth0.com/2013/06/05/connect-windows-azure-active-directory-with-salesforce-dropbox-sharepoint-zendesk/). (See the diagram at the bottom off the page, replace any of the packaged apps with your own API).

However, I'm not 100% certain Azure AD supports WS-Trust (it didn't last time I checked). So you might need to use the technique I describe before (using browsers).

In any case, once you obtain the token, you will send it to the API. Securing the WebApi endpoints will likely involve using [JsonWebTokenHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt). An example of this is available [here](https://docs.auth0.com/webapi#6).

Final note: you might want to consider using Windows Azure Mobile Services. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a basic ADFS architecture question, completely unrelated to tablets, mobile, phonegap, or relying parties at all. I think what you're missing is that you're SUPPOSED to have your ADFS server behind a firewall completely inaccessible to everyone. Then you setup a proxy in a DMZ that your clients talk to, and then the proxy can talk to your ADFS server.

Remember, one of the biggest benefits of federated login is so that the security token can come from somewhere outside of your network (e.g. from a partnering company, or google, Microsoft, facebook, etc.) It's intended that you set your servers up in a way that people can initiate a request from outside your network. ADFS would have greatly diminished value if this weren't the case.